# IBM Worklight/Mobilefirst migration from worklight 6.1 to mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server, worklight-runtime, mobilefirst-runtime

I am planning to migrate an existing worklight 6.1 application to mobilefirst 7.1.Currently *three* versions of application are running.

I am following this as my reference :
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_in_production_env.html

But I am going to do some process change in this process because I have a fresh server for mobilefirst 7.1.

As in mobilefirst 7.1, there are many changes in workligth db in compare to worklight 6.1, I will create a configuration first on mf server using server configuration tool. Then I will create a runtime environment for my application with lates mobilefirst 7.1 war.

But while doing that if I give reference of older database(worklight 6.1) as database in server configuration tool for migration , are all version which are currently running on worklight will run without error on mobilefirst 7.1?

Should I keep contextroot of mf runtime same as worklight (previous) ?

All I want is older versions to be up and running after this deployment.
I will enable mf server on same Domain/IP which is configured with worklight 6.1 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But while doing that if I give reference of older database(worklight 6.1) as database, are all version which are currently running on worklight will run without error on mobilefirst 7.1?

Not sure what you mean here... You can't have a 7.1 server with a 6.1 database.

What you *can* have is an application server (liberty, was, tomcat, ...) that runs TWO MobileFirst war files: that of 6.1 and that of 7.1, so that existing 6.1-based apps will continue working as-is, and 7.1 new clients will connect to the new server...

When you have the two servers running, you can then start "migrating" users by blocking the 6.1 app in the MobileFirst Console to the 7.1 version of the app.

If you need further assistance with this, you should open a PMR. Stack Overflow is not the place for this type of question, plus you may need official support, which, again, that's what a PMR is for.

Comment: When I say database of 6.1, I mean worklight database which is configured with worklight 6.1. So when I migrate that database using server configuration tool,   all wlapp will get migrated.  So that can be connected from client running applications?  Application server is WAS ND with clustering.

Comment: Can you help me with this?

Comment: You need official support. Open a PMR.